# Trouble with Basic scan and print functions within C

Tags: c

Write a statement that asks the user to type three integers, then write a second statement that stores the three user responses into first, second, and third.

I've made multiple attempts at this yet have fallen short with errors I do not see being made in my code. I also think if I can do this with one variable I can do it with three

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int integer;  

    printf("Enter a integer> ");   
    scanf_s("%d", &integer);
    printf("first = %d\n");
    return(0);
}
```

many times it will say i have undefined identifiers.

Comment: `printf("first = %d\n");` -> `printf("first = %d\n", integer);`

Comment: Note that `scanf_s()` is a *de facto* Microsoft-only, non-portable* version of `scanf()` that isn't really any safer than `scanf()` is.  Don't believe the "This function has been deprecated" warnings you get from Visual Studio.  `scanf()` is fully standard C.  * - Pedantically, it's from the optional Annex K of the C 11 Standard, but only Microsoft implemented that - and they didn't even implement their functions per Annex K anyway.

Comment: I've read alot about the VS version of scanf, huge help for clarifying. thank you my dude

Answer (score 1):

For the second printf, you need to pass a variable that holds an integer value. In your case it's the variable integer.So,
printf("first = %d\n", integer); should fix it.

Comment: Maybe instead of the word "assign" you should use "include".

Comment: I'd suggest 'pass' as a better term than 'assign' _or_ 'include'.  You pass variables or values to functions.